# Scope issues inside an Event Listener?

Tags: javascript

The following code basically shows/hides paragraph tags, I'm having to re-declare the `paras` variable. Is this because I'm dynamically injecting the `button` into the DOM, or is it to do with scope? How could I better construct this markup?

```
// vars
var revealContainer = document.querySelector('.reveal-more');
var paras = revealContainer.querySelectorAll('p');
var status = true;

// return
if (paras && paras.length <= 3) return;

// generate show more link
revealContainer.innerHTML += '<button class="button--text reveal-more__btn">Read more</button>';
var revealBtn = revealContainer.querySelector('.reveal-more__btn');

// click event
revealBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {

    var paras = revealContainer.querySelectorAll('p');

    // toggle show/hide class
    for (var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
        var p = paras[i];
        p.classList.toggle('is-shown');
    }

    // check status
    if (status) {
        this.textContent = 'Read less';
        status = false;
    } else {
        this.textContent = 'Read more';
        status = true;
    }

});
```

Comment: It's not really scope-related, but rather runtime-related. Consider that if you're adding elements dynamically, your querySelectorAll won't be able to be aware of that if it was executed **before** the DOM injection.

Comment: @briosheje Yes exactly. What would be a nice way to refactor this code so I'm not re-declaring?

Comment: If you want to add events to dynamically you might want to look in delegated events.  Fancy name, but it's basically were you attach the event listener further up the DOM, and due to how events bubble you can capture the events there,. And using some simple Javascript comparison find out if this an element your interested in and do your stuff.

Comment: Using delegated events may be a better fit for your application. It basically uses the fact that events bubble up the DOM tree so you can register the listener on to a static parent from where you can handle it as needed. [Handy intro to event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

Comment: Thanks @keith. I've previously done this in jQuery but not in vanilla JS.

Comment: That's one of those cases where the good old `.getElementsByTagName()` and its returned _live HTMLCollection_  is really handy. It will always have the current state of the selected elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *live* [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) instead of the *static* [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) returned by [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> The `getElementsByTagName` method of [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) interface returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of elements with the given tag name. The complete document is searched, including the root node. **The returned `HTMLCollection` is live, meaning that it updates itself automatically to stay in sync with the DOM tree without having to call `document.getElementsByTagName()` again.**

```js
var paragraphs = document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("p");
console.log(paragraphs.length);

setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("container").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>p</p>");
}, 1000);

setInterval(function() {
  console.log(paragraphs.length);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a really simple Snippet that demonstrates delegated events in pure Javascript, instead of using jQuery.

Here you can see I've attached the eventListener to the div with id `elements`, this will then listen for `click` events under this,  a simple `matches` is used just in case you have other elements your not interested in..

```js
document.querySelector("#elements").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (!e.target.matches('.element')) return
  console.log(`Clicked ${e.target.innerText}`);
});
```

```css
.element {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="elements">
  <div class="element">1</div>
  <div class="element">2</div>
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <div>Clicking this does nothing.</div>
</div>
```